# Finding partial matching row

Tags: excel

Hi How am able to find two partial matching cell?

For example:

A1 contain Apple Carrot Elephant in worksheet 1

B2 contain Apple Banana Carrot drinks in worksheet 2

After that it will output the difference next to cell 5 of worksheet 2

C2 contain Banana drinks in worksheet 2

Thank you

```
Public lRowA as Long
Public lRowB as Long

Sub compare()

dim LCA as interger
dim LCB as interger

Sheet1.Activate
call rangemethodA
Sheet2.Activate 
call rangemethodB

For LCA= 2 to lRowA

For LCB= 2 to lRowB

if InStr(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & LCB), Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & LCA)) > 0 Then

WORDDIF (Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & LCA),  Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & LCB))
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & LCB).value = WORDDIF 

Else 

Goto NextLCB

Endif

NextLCB:

Next LCB

Next LCA

End sub



Function WORDDIF(rngA As Range, rngB As Range) As String
    
    Dim WordsA As Variant, WordsB As Variant
    Dim ndxA As Long, ndxB As Long, strTemp As String
        
    WordsA = Split(rngA.Text, " ")
    WordsB = Split(rngB.Text, " ")
    
    For ndxB = LBound(WordsB) To UBound(WordsB)
        For ndxA = LBound(WordsA) To UBound(WordsA)
            If StrComp(WordsA(ndxA), WordsB(ndxB), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                WordsA(ndxA) = vbNullString
                Exit For
            End If
        Next ndxA
    Next ndxB
    
    For ndxA = LBound(WordsA) To UBound(WordsA)
strTemp = strTemp & IIf(WordsA(ndxA) <> vbNullString, WordsA(ndxA), "-") & " "
    Next ndxA
    
    WORDDIF = Trim(strTemp)
End Function
```

Comment: You could use Power Query; create two `Lists` from each string; and `RemoveMatchingItems` in the second list that match from the first.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a custom function and loop using `Split`, assuming space is always the delimiter.

```
Function CompareDiff(v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant) As String

Dim a1, a2, i As Long

a1 = Split(v1, " ")
a2 = Split(v2, " ")
For i = LBound(a2) To UBound(a2)
    If IsError(Application.Match(a2(i), a1, 0)) Then
        CompareDiff = CompareDiff & a2(i)
    End If
Next i

End Function
```

Call it thus:

```
Sub xx()

'call function thus

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2").Value = CompareDiff(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2"))

End Sub
```

Of course, the more obvious usage is directly in the sheet like a normal formula, e.g.

```
=CompareDiff(A1,B1)
```

Comment: Thanks i will give it a try.